# Releasing only new version of a sub-module in maven

Tags: maven-3

Here is my use-case:
Assume that I have multi-module maven project in which I make a change only in one of its sub-modules. After the change has been made, I want to release only a new version of this sub-module and not releasing the whole project.

Is there a way to do that in maven?

What maven recommends in this case as a best practice?

Is it a good practice to have different sub-module versions?

Comment: About how many modules are we talking about?

Comment: Does not matter. Assume that I have an api and core sub-modules where the api sub-module changes less frequently than the core sub-module. I am trying to figure out is it a good practice to have different sub-module versions or the idea of multi-module projects is to have one version for all.

Answer (score 0):

First as you asked. The idea of a multi module build is to have the same version of all modules which might mean releasing modules which haven't been changed.
BUT:

If you start to have different versions in child modules you will loose the idea and the support which leads to manual work....

Furthermore if you release different versions of the childs you have to asure that different versions of childs work correctly together which means in other words you have to do testing on different version combinations of that which would increase the testing effort dramatically. 
if you use only a single version of the modules a customer can chose simply one version and can be sure the components working correctly together...I assume you have some unit/integration tests within your build...

Comment: But don't you agree that if I have changes only in one sub-module and the  others stay the same, making a reactor build of the whole project is a waste of time and resources.

Comment: If you only take a look at the build time and the resources for artifacts you are right but it's trade off between those resources and the effort for testing this correctly. If you change the project structure into several independent projects to have separated deployments and release versions which would solve the problem but only on the first glance. Cause you have to maintain all those artifacts manually which is really hard the larger you multi module structure is...At the moment i have a project which contains more than 300 modules the waste is only a bit of storage..which is cheap...

Comment: If we are talking about only build time this can reduced by using `mvn -pl TheModuleChange clean package` which reduces the build time if you have a larger number of modules...

Comment: to summarize: it is possible that in a multi-module project, some of the sub-modules may have different version than the one specified in parent pom, but this is considered a violation of the way mvn multi-module projects are intended to be used and lead to inconsistent state of the project

Comment: I wouldn't call it inconstistent state. I would call it more a less mantainable situation which causes more manual work (test, confusion on consumer site) than it saves in equivalence of resources (storage and may be build time) on the other hand.

Comment: I just found very good [explanation](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html) about how you should organize your project and why it is not necessary (it depends on the case) to have parent/child relationship